# Create two(2) edge flanges in Solidworks with VBA

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

Dear SolidWorks users,

I am using SW2012 and via VBA I like to create **two(2) edge flanges**. I have the following code, this creates one edge flange after you select one edge of the sheet metal.

I like to know how can I add(put) 2 selections edge in an array? Like that (maybe), can be created two(2) edge flanges.

In the function of `.InsertSheetMetalEdgeFlange2` it is mention that this function can accept array selection and array sketch.

Thank you.

```
    Sub Bends_2()

    Dim swApp            As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel          As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swEdge           As SldWorks.Edge
    Dim swFeature        As SldWorks.Feature
    Dim swEntity         As SldWorks.Entity
    Dim swSketch         As SldWorks.Sketch
    Dim swSketchLine     As SldWorks.SketchLine
    Dim swStartPoint     As SldWorks.SketchPoint
    Dim swEndPoint       As SldWorks.SketchPoint
    Dim aFlangeEdges(0)  As SldWorks.Edge
    Dim aSketchFeats(0)  As SldWorks.Sketch
    Dim vFlangeEdges     As Variant
    Dim vSketchFeats     As Variant
    Dim bValue           As Boolean
    Dim dAngle           As Double
    Dim dLength          As Double
    Dim vSketchSegments  As Variant

    
    ' Connect to SOLIDWORKS
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    
    ' Get active document
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

   ' Set the angle +length
    dAngle = (90# / 180#) * 3.1415926535897
    dLength = 25 / 1000

    swModel.ShowNamedView2 "*Trimetric", -1
    swModel.ViewZoomtofit2
    
    ' Get edge
    Set swEdge = swModel.SelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
    
    ' Insert a sketch for an Edge Flange
    Set swFeature = swModel.InsertSketchForEdgeFlange(swEdge, dAngle, False)
    
    ' Select
    bValue = swFeature.Select2(False, 0)
    
    ' Start sketch editing
    swModel.EditSketch
    
    ' Get the active sketch
    Set swSketch = swModel.GetActiveSketch2
    
    ' Add the edge to the sketch
    Set swEntity = swEdge

    
    ' Select edge
    bValue = swEntity.Select4(False, Nothing)
    
    ' Use the edge in the sketch
    bValue = swModel.SketchManager.SketchUseEdge(False)
    
    ' Get the created sketch line
    vSketchSegments = swSketch.GetSketchSegments

    
    Set swSketchLine = vSketchSegments(0)
    
    ' Get start and end point
    Set swStartPoint = swSketchLine.GetStartPoint2
    Set swEndPoint = swSketchLine.GetEndPoint2
    

    ' Create additional lines to define sketch
    swModel.SetAddToDB True
    swModel.SetDisplayWhenAdded False
    swModel.CreateLine2 swStartPoint.X, swStartPoint.Y, 0#, swStartPoint.X, swStartPoint.Y + dLength, 0#
    swModel.CreateLine2 swStartPoint.X, swStartPoint.Y + dLength, 0#, swEndPoint.X, swStartPoint.Y + dLength, 0#
    swModel.CreateLine2 swEndPoint.X, swEndPoint.Y, 0#, swEndPoint.X, swEndPoint.Y + dLength, 0#

    'reset
    swModel.SetDisplayWhenAdded True
    swModel.SetAddToDB False

    
    ' Commit changes made to the sketch
    swModel.InsertSketch2 True
    
    Set aFlangeEdges(0) = swEdge
    Set aSketchFeats(0) = swSketch

    
    vFlangeEdges = aFlangeEdges
    vSketchFeats = aSketchFeats

    'create edge flange
    Set swFeature = swModel.FeatureManager.InsertSheetMetalEdgeFlange2((vFlangeEdges), (vSketchFeats), 128, dAngle, 0.7 / 1000, swFlangePositionTypes_e.swFlangePositionTypeMaterialInside, dLength, swSheetMetalReliefTypes_e.swSheetMetalReliefNone, 0#, 0#, 0#, swFlangeDimTypes_e.swFlangeDimTypeInnerVirtualSharp, Nothing)

End Sub
```